# SubscriptionCountReached' has reached limit of '1000'

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am setting up subscriptions to M365 mailboxes so I can receive a change notification event when something happens to that mailbox. This has been working fine until recently when I started receiving this error:

```
Status Code: 429; Reason: Resource 'SubscriptionCountReached' has reached limit of '1000'.  Please retry after '12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM
```

Ideally, I just want to delete all subscriptions setup on my M365 tenant, but cannot find where these exist in the Portal UI.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to clear out the old subscriptions that seem to be hanging around?

Answer (score 1):

> **`Status Code: 429`**;
> Reason: Resource 'SubscriptionCountReached' has reached limit of '1000'.  Please retry after '12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM

The above error usually occurs when you reach the **maximum quota** of times(1000) that are predetermined.

According to this [**Microsoft Doc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks#azure-ad-resource-limitations), the maximum subscription quota for Azure AD resources are as follow:

[image]

To **delete** all the subscriptions set up in your **`M365 tenant`**, try steps mentioned in below link:

[**Delete subscriptions of Azure AD tenant - Azure Active Directory | Microsoft Docs**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/directory-delete-howto#delete-a-subscription)

- To allow deletion, subscriptions must be in ***Deprovisioned*** state.
- An ***Expired*** or ***Canceled*** subscription will initially move to the **Disabled** state, and the final stage is the **Deprovisioned** state.

The simple way to cancel your subscription is to ***turn off recurring billing*** option in order to prevent other charges.

If you added your ***own domain name*** to use with your subscription, you must remove the domain before cancelling subscription.

> **The expired subscription will send several notifications. It can be deleted automatically after 90 days and will be deleted no later than 180 days.**

For more in detail, please find below **links** if they are helpful.

**References:**

[azure - Microsoft Graph. Exception : reached limit of '1000' - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65494288/microsoft-graph-exception-subscriptioncountreached-has-reached-limit-of-1000)

[Cancel your subscription | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/commerce/subscriptions/cancel-your-subscription?view=o365-worldwide)

[Delete expired subscription - Microsoft Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/delete-expired-subscription/e1d57d02-382f-4e05-a890-b39de359f0a933647f97d8a3&view=o365-worldwide)

Comment: Hey @nosajsnikta! had it solved your problem else you can share more details so I can troubleshoot?